# Will it hurt my computer if I remove the copies of standard directories like Documents and Downloads Windows installed on each of my hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, windows-11

My laptop has two distinct hard drives. The smaller one is a solid state drive and is where I install programs and keep current projects that are computationally intensive. The second is three terabytes of conventional hard drive, not slow but definitely slower. Although I did not create them, the second drive has all the standard Windows directories: Documents, Desktop, Downloads and the like. I have assumed that Windows 11 itself installed these directories.

Is this second set of Windows directories necessary? Occasionally my browsers and other programs get confused and send stuff to these directories rather than their SSD equivalents. I use this anthropomorphic language because I am quite sure I have never intentionally downloaded things to any of those directories, and as far as I can see their only function is to create opportunities to lose files. I use that drive primarily to store large data sets – Census files, mainly – which I keep in directories with informative names. But there is a lot of stuff in these directories, and my preference would be to move it all to the same-named directories on the SSD, and then, if it will not break things, delete the directories on the regular drive.

Is there any chance that this would brick my machine, or have other scary consequences?

Comment: From the directory containing the folders on the mechanical HDD, please post the output of `cmd /c dir /a:s`, as well as the output from `cmd /c dir /a:s %UserProfile%`. within code boxes. Without that info, it's not possible to provide an answer or how to resolve.

Comment: Take a look with Nirsoft's SpecialFoldersView, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/special_folders_view.html, which displays the full environment path for those folders. E.G., `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` for *Documents*. It might help determine where the second set came from. *Do not* simply delete the spurious folders; use Explorer to change their location.

Answer (score 0):

It's not normal to have two copies of Documents etc. more than
once. The only explanation I can give is that you have more
than one user accounts, where their home folders are on two
separate disks. Or that you have once relocated your home folder.

In any case, it's impossible for applications to randomly switch
to another Documents folder than your one (explained below).

You may see your folders in the registry under key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\User Shell Folders`.
Note that all use `%USERPROFILE%`, where `USERPROFILE` is a
"volatile" environment variable, meaning that it's created when
your login is started. You may consult the values under the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment`.

I suggest to verify in the registry where your folders
are located.
This is the only set of folders that you need to conserve,
assuming that they do not belong to another user account.